# ListView in Widgets not displaying elements

Tags: java, android, listview, android-widget

I have a ListView inside a RelativeLayout inside a Widget.
There is a RemoteViewsFactory that is hooked up to it.
WidgetAdapterService -> The RemoteViewService that is hooked up to the ListView.
NewAppWidget -> The Main widget class.

The widget does not display any elements.

NetworkUtils contains a list of arrays that contain data previously and I've checked that it gives correct results when I set the first element of the array to a TextView.

I'm unsure as to why the ListView itself isn't displaying any elements.

NewAppWidget.java

```
          package devapp.com.bakingappudacity;

    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
    import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
    import android.content.ComponentName;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.RemoteViews;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import devapp.com.bakingappudacity.utils.NetworkUtils;
    import devapp.com.bakingappudacity.utils.WidgetAdapterService;

    /**
    * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
     */
    public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int[] appWidgetId) {

    CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetAdapterService.class);

    views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list_view,intent);

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

            // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
            //Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
            //Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetAdapterService.class);
            //views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list_view,intent);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetAdapterService.class);

            views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list_view,intent);


            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created

    AppWidgetManager appManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget.class);

    updateAppWidget(context,appManager,appManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget));

}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}
 }
```

WidgetAdapterService.java

```
         package devapp.com.bakingappudacity.utils;

      import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.RemoteViewsService;
import android.widget.Toast;

 import devapp.com.bakingappudacity.R;

public class WidgetAdapterService extends RemoteViewsService{

@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return new WidgetAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());
}
 }

class WidgetAdapter implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

private Context context;

WidgetAdapter(Context mContext){

    context = mContext;

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NetworkUtils.RECIPE_NAMES.size();
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

    RemoteViews item = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_list_item);
    item.setTextViewText(R.id.recipe_list_item_text_view,NetworkUtils.RECIPE_NAMES.get(position));

    return item;
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
    }
```

new_app_widget.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#09C"
android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/widget_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

widget_list_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget_list_view_item_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="TextView" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the permission android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS 
in the manifest when registering the service.